Incidence influenced by test frequency
I’m puzzled with a study design. Say I want to study a disease incidence, but this disease is asymptomatic mostly and its detection merely relies on regular testing. Some people test more frequently than others. I’d like to assign weight to each person based on their test frequency. If I plan to use inverse propensity score to calculate weight (just an example):
PS= glm(test_frequency~age+sex, data=df)
PS$Wt= 1/predict(PS, df)

Does this sound reasonable?
Many thanks!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
